# What is the underlying type of a c++ enum?

Tags: c++, enums, size, types, hex

This may have been answered elsewhere but I could not find a suitable response.

I have this code:

```
enum enumWizardPage
{
    WP_NONE = 0x00,  
    WP_CMDID = 0x01,    
    WP_LEAGUES = 0x02,  
    WP_TEAMS = 0x04,    
    WP_COMP = 0x08, 
    WP_DIVISIONS = 0x10,
    WP_FORMULAS = 0x20, 
    WP_FINISHED = 0x40, 
};
```

Which is legacy and I have to modify it by adding a few new values.
The issue is each value must be a unique bit so they may be OR combined to a bitmap.

The values are set using the #x## hex format, but I'm wondering if this is the max it can store?
What will be the effect, if any, if I change my code to

```
enum enumWizardPage
{
    WP_NONE = 0x0000,  
    WP_CMDID = 0x0001,  
    WP_LEAGUES = 0x0002,    
    WP_TEAMS = 0x0004,  
    WP_COMP = 0x0008,   
    WP_DIVISIONS = 0x0010,
    WP_FORMULAS = 0x0020,   
    WP_FINISHED = 0x0040,   
};
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

From [N4659 C++ 7.2/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.enum#7):

> For an enumeration whose underlying type is not fixed, the underlying type is an integral type that can represent all the enumerator values defined in the enumeration. If no integral type can represent all the enumerator values, the enumeration is ill-formed. It is implementation-defined which integral type is used as the underlying type except that the underlying type shall not be larger than `int` unless the value of an enumerator cannot fit in an `int` or `unsigned int`. If the *enumerator-list* is empty, the underlying type is as if the enumeration had a single enumerator with value 0.

Answer (score 81):

The type of a C++ enum is the enum itself. Its range is rather arbitrary, but in practical terms, its underlying type is an `int`.

It is implicitly cast to `int` wherever it's used, though.

#### C++11 changes

This has changed since C++11, which introduced typed enums. An untyped `enum` now is defined as being at least the width of `int` (and wider if larger values are needed). However, given a typed `enum` defined as follows:

```
enum name : type {};
```

An enumeration of type `name` has an underlying type of `type`. For example, `enum : char` defines an `enum` the same width as `char` instead of `int`.

Further, an `enum` can be explicitly scoped as follows:

```
enum class name : type {
    value = 0,
    // ...
};
```

(Where `name` is required, but `type` is optional.) An `enum` declared this way will no longer implicitly cast to its underlying type (requiring a `static_cast<>`) and values must be referenced with a fully-qualified name. In this example, to assign `value` to an `enum` variable, you must refer to it as `name::value`.

Answer (score 5):

IIRC its represented as int in memory. But gcc has switch `-fshort-enum` to make it a shortest integer type that fits all the values, if you need to save space. Other compilers will have something similar.