# Is there a way to serialize automatically enums as int?

Tags: c++, serialization, enums

Is there a way to serialize enums automatically as int? Every time I define a new enum and write

```
std::stringstream stream;
stream << myenum1;
stream >> myenum2;
```

the compiler complains that the operators << and >> are not defined. Do you know a way to tell the compiler to treat enums as plain int's?

What makes the problem harder is that, actually, the serialization is inside a template. Something like this:

```
template <typename T>
void serialize(const T& value)
{
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << value;
}
```

So I cannot add any casts :(
Maybe I can specialize it somehow?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find out if the type is enum with boost's TypeTraits ([is_enum](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_enum.html)).

Then you can combine this with `enable_if` / `disable_if`:

```
template <class T>
typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_enum<T> >::type serialize(const T&);

template <class T>
typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_enum<T> >::type serialize(const T&); //use casts here
```

However, it will not be possible to check if a given value is valid for a given enum (unless you write a specific overload for the given enum type).

Comment: You could check validity using another template trait

Comment: @Autopulated: How would that look like? (Also, aren't ORed enum constants also valid values for an enum?)

Comment: Well, it depends how your using your enums, but broadly speaking, overload the trait for each type, and use something like a max_value enum value in each enum type. The advantage of using a trait is that you can have a default that allows everything to be accepted, or accepts a predefined range as you like.

Answer (score 3):

For output, the `<<` operator will promote any enum type to the closest fit of `int` or `long`. (§5.8/1, 4.5/2) You shouldn't be having any problems, and I couldn't produce any with GCC or Comeau. Correct me if I'm wrong.

For input, you can write a template function and disable implicit instantiation by hiding it inside an only-explicitly instantiated class.

```
template< class E >
struct enum_traits {
    friend std::istream &operator>> ( std::istream &is, E &e ) {
        long i; // or intmax_t, whatever
        std::istream &r = is >> i;
        e = E( i );
        return r;
    }
};

enum my_enum { a, b, c };
template class enum_traits< my_enum >; // explicit instantiation
   // "matching declaration" per 7.3.1.2/3:
std::istream &operator>> ( std::istream &, my_enum & );
```

This passes GCC and Comeau. I can't find a way to wrangle namespaces and ADL to make it any more convenient. (Only alternate solution involves a using declaration for every enumerator.)

But the two boilerplate declarations can be wrapped in a macro, or in any case they're better than writing the whole function over again!

Comment: Two years later: note that C++11 scoped enumerators don't implicitly convert for `<<`, so you would use the same pattern for output as input. The problem with UncleBen's answer is that it doesn't depend on a user-defined class, so isn't strictly standard compliant. Another similar template would generate a conflict, but a simple overload for a particular enum type would have no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try casting the enums to integers, using, e.g., `static_cast<int>(enumX)`?

Comment: I cannot cast it since it is inside of a templated code. I've updated the question to be more clear.

Comment: The underlying type of an enumeration is not necessarily `int`. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122096) for more details.

Comment: @FireAphis: Could you not have a second type that you pass to the template that is the type you should cast to?

Answer (score 1):

> Do you know a way to tell the compiler to treat enums as plain int's?

This is not possible (at least for >>), as it would be not type safe (assigning int to enum is not type safe).

One thing you can do is to provide your overloads of operators >> and << for each enum, which will do the casting for you. This is something you will do for each enum once, which sounds a lot better than having to the cast on each place where you use >>/<< (which comes especially handy here as you cannot edit the places where those operators are used).

Comment: That is exactly what I want to avoid - adding an operator each time I add an enum. Isn't there a generic way to do it?

Comment: Using SFINAE you might be able to provide some operator template which would use is_enum to detect the enums - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982983.aspx. If and how exactly this would work is something I would have to think a lot harder, which I currently am not able to do.

Answer (score 0):

It'll get better with C++0x, since you'll be able to state the underlying type (for example `unsigned short`).

For now you have to use a convention, for example assuming that all your enum values can be stored within an `int` you can serialize and deserialize it as int and then convert it back.

The other issue is of course your serialization routine:

```
std::stringstream stream;
stream << 1 << 2;
int a;
stream >> a;
assert(a == 12);
```

Usually serialization involves taking some binary representation of a known size (or serializing the size along it). If you don't want to deal with it yourself, there are libraries:

- Boost.Serialization
- Google.ProtocolBuffers

And both have plain text and binary representation (and plain text is way easier to debug).