# What happens if an enum cannot fit into an integral type?

Tags: c++, types, enums, size

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122096/what-is-the-underlying-type-of-a-c-enum) about the underlying types of enums, where an answers quotes Standard C++ 7.2/5 as:

> The underlying type of an enumeration is an integral type that can represent all the enumerator values defined in the enumeration. It is implementation-defined which integral type is used as the underlying type for an enumeration except that the underlying type shall not be larger than int unless the value of an enu- merator cannot fit in an int or unsigned int.

This is pretty clear for all reasonable cases. **But what happens if I make an enum so ridiculously large that it can't even fit in a long long?**

(I don't know why this would ever happen in practice, but maybe I'm feeling destructive and have a free afternoon)

**Is this behavior defined by the standard?**

Comment: If you make an `enum` that large, your source file wouldn't fit on disk :-)

Comment: I was envisioning a truly horrifying header file with more than 2^64 names in the enum. Would that not work?

Comment: It's surprisingly simple to contrive it, see my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The behaviour of

```
enum foo : int
{
    bar = INT_MAX,
    oops
};
```

and similar is *undefined*.

I've cheated a little here by forcing the type to an `int`, but the same applies to the largest integral type available on your platform.

Comment: Is it also UB when the enum's underlying type is `unsigned`?

Comment: Oh that is a beautiful question. Please ask it! I will instantly upvote that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39621098/what-happens-if-an-enum-cannot-fit-into-an-unsigned-integral-type