# How enum can be used as string

Tags: objective-c, string, enums

I have CurrentType as enum in a class like following:

```
typedef enum {
        login = 0,
        Details,
        SendImages,
       UpdateDetails,

}CurrentType;
```

Now In another ViewController,I want to use this CurrentType as parameter like as follows:

```
-(void)getLoginUserDetails:(NSData *)response :(CurrentType)service{
```

But when I write the following in method body

```
service==UpdateDetails
```

it gives error

How can I use this CurrentType as parameter ???

Comment: Show the complete code causing the error and post the actual error.

Comment: You need to import that class in which your enum is declared, then only you are able to use that enum in another class.

Comment: which error you are getting ? please post here.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Concerning your subject: Enums in (Objective-)C are of an [integral type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1122128/6319106) like `int`or `long`. You can't assign or cast enums to strings directly, but rather have to implement your own conversion function.

Comment: as per user question he is asking for something else `How can I use this CurrentType as parameter ???`