# Underlying type of an unscoped enum?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am observing the following behavior under Visual Studio 2013 (Debug/Win32 compilation). Consider the following c++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  enum { V = (unsigned long long)ULLONG_MAX } E;
  std::cout << sizeof E << std::endl;

  enum : unsigned long long { W = (unsigned long long)ULLONG_MAX } F;
  std::cout << sizeof F << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

After compilation this leads to:

```
$ ./enum.exe
4
8
```

If I understand the c++ standard correctly ([Standard C++ 7.2/5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1122128/136285)), this is an invalid c++ behavior. In this case, I should not be required to define the underlying type explicitly, since the value of an enumerator cannot fit in an `int` or `unsigned int`.

So:

1. Is this is a well known limitation of Visual Studio 2013 (maybe other versions are affected) ?
2. Is there a way to force the compiler to use a proper underlying type for a c++98 style enum ? Or am I required to switch to c++11 notation with fixed-type ?

---

Update: as suggested I reported a problem at:

- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/524018/underlying-type-of-an-unscoped-enum.html

Comment: latest VC compiler gives the same result.gcc and clang - 8 and 8 (as expected). Looks like a VC bug

Comment: Printing `V` gives `-1` on MSVC, odd.

Comment: No warning with ``/Wall`` or ``/permissive-`` with VS 2017 (15.9). You should file this as a bug on [VS Connect](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/).

Comment: It’s not much different, but using the [current draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#7) is generally a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The reference says the following (important parts bolded):

> Declares an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is not
>   fixed (in this case, **the underlying type is an implementation-defined
>   integral type that can represent all enumerator values**; this type is
>   not larger than int **unless the value of an enumerator cannot fit in an
>   int or unsigned int**. If the enumerator-list is empty, the underlying
>   type is as if the enumeration had a single enumerator with value 0).

*and*

> Values of unscoped enumeration type are implicitly-convertible to
>   integral types. If the underlying type is not fixed, **the value is
>   convertible to the first type from the following list able to hold
>   their entire value range**: int, unsigned int, long, unsigned long, long
>   long, or **unsigned long long**. If the underlying type is fixed, the
>   values can be converted to their promoted underlying type.

Taken together, it is *clear* that it is a bug with [msvc](/questions/tagged/msvc) (probably introduced at some point). What makes matters worse is that it is *sort of* silent about this.