# Passing in an enum type in to function?

Tags: c++, enums

I haven't used enums in the past and I'm currently working with a codebase that uses enums and I need to pass them into a function. My understanding is enums are integers, e.g.,

```
typedef enum {
  toyota = 0,
  honda = 1, 
  volkswagen = 2
} car_brand_t;
```

If I want to write a function void `func` that can be called like
`func(toyota)`, what should the parameter type be? Can I simply use `int` like below, or is there something more sophisticated?

```
void func(int enum_type);
```

Comment: `enum` in an actual type, why don't you say what you mean and just have `void func(car_brand_t);`?

Comment: @Neil I think I misunderstood `enum`. I thought it worked more like a namespace than an actual type?

Comment: In C, all the `enums` get mashed together into one namespace; seems like a good idea to use C++11 scoped enum as in the answer. Enums are limited to a (signed?) integral type, but, unless you have good reason for assigning specific values, it would be more transparent to have the compiler to make the choice.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a good C++ code, it is C code. In C++ you do it like this:

```cpp
enum car_brand_t
{
  toyota = 0,
  honda = 1, 
  volkswagen = 2
};

void func(car_brand_t value);
```

With usage: `func(toyota)`

You can also use more type-safe **scoped enum**:

```cpp
enum class car_brand_t
{
  toyota = 0,
  honda = 1, 
  volkswagen = 2
};

void func(car_brand_t value);
```

With usage: `func(car_brand_t::toyota)`

**APPENDIX**

As you asked more specific question, I should extend my answer.

> Just want want to confirm that in C++ the enum listings are limited to integers?

Yes, they are integers, signed or unsigned and including `bool` type. If it is not explicitly defined, compiler [is free to choose the type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122096/what-is-the-underlying-type-of-a-c-enum). Specific underlying type can be extracted by a `std::underlying_type` from `<type_traits>` header:

```cpp
enum car_brand_t
{
  toyota = 0,
  honda = 1, 
  volkswagen = 2
};

using the_type = std::underlying_type<car_brand_t>::type; // C++11
using the_type = std::underlying_type_t<car_brand_t>; // C++14
```

Most popular compilers will choose `unsigned int` for the example `car_brand_t` type (as it doesn't contain negative values).

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<unsigned, std::underlying_type_t<car_brand_t>>);
```

If you need,you can **specify underlying type explicitly**, with the following syntax:

```
enum car_brand_t : short
{
  toyota = 0,
  honda = 1, 
  volkswagen = 2
};
```

or

```
enum class car_brand_t : std::uint8_t
{
  toyota = 0,
  honda = 1, 
  volkswagen = 2
};
```

This may be very useful, especially when you want to:

- Have forward declaration of your enum type `enum car_brand_t : short;`
- Want to serialize the byte-pattern of some struct containing fixed-size enum:

```
enum class car_brand_t : std::uint16_t;
struct car_data
{
  car_brand_t brand;
  std::uint16_t manufacture_year;
};

static_assert(
    sizeof(car_data) == 4 &&
    std::has_unique_object_representations_v<car_data> &&
    std::is_trivially_copyable<car_data>
);
```

Comment: Ah I see. Just want want to confirm that in C++ the enum listings are limited to integers? I think in some other languages we can have floats

Comment: @westcoaststudent • yes, C++ enums are limited to integers.